# Exporting Logical Volume to Mac for use as Time Machine drive

Tags: ubuntu, osx, samba, fstab

I have an Ubuntu server, and I have put a hard drive into this server. The logical volume on this hard drive looks like

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976773167   488385560   8e  Linux LVM
```

this has a ext3 file system.

What do I have to do to get this hard drive working with my time machine.

Is there anything special I have to do in fstab so that it mounts correctly?

Also, how do I set up the samba config file? What should the config look like for the newly mounted hard drive ?

Comment: I don't know the answer but [have you googled for the answer](http://www.zerga.de/wordpress/2011/10/13/howto-get-macosx-lion-time-machine-to-backup-on-a-samba-share/) and not found it?

Comment: please post your current `/etc/fstab` on the server and the current smb configuration. What have you tried?